# Is possible to group items according to a front matter variable in Jekyll?

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I have a list of cities, each of one contains some stores. I want to loop through each city listing the stores contained in them, and once the loop list all of the stores continues with another city.

Sample html:

```
<div class="card-group">
  <h5 class="heading heading-5">City 1</h5>
   <div class="card card-store">
     <h6 class="heading heading-6"><a href="">Store 1</a></h5>
   </div>
   <div class="card card-store">
     <h6 class="heading heading-6"><a href="">Store 2</a></h5>
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="card-group">
 <h5 class="heading heading-5">City 2</h5>
 <div class="card card-store">
  <h6 class="heading heading-6"><a href="#">Store 3</a></h5>
 </div>
</div>
```

Currently, I'm setting up a collection with a file for each store with a front matter set like this:

> ```
> ---
> title: Store 1
> city: City 1
> ---
> ```

I'm trying to figure it out with an if condition the compares the "City" variable. The number of cities is limited, but the stores will grow. I'm not sure if this approach is correct, or if I should create a folder for each city and use something like the "page.collection" variable. 
The final project will be deployed in a headless CMS.

Comment: Updating the question:

Comment: Have a look at `group_by` filter. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjekyll%5D+group_by

Answer (score 0):

Ok, is not the most elegant solution but it works! What I did was:

1. Create _cities and _stores collections.
2. Create a "city" front matter variable in the store.
3. Loop it:

   ```
   {% for city in site.cities %}
    <h5 class="heading heading-5"> {{ city.title }} </h5>
    {% for store in site.stores %}
     {% if city.title == store.city %}
        ##DO STUFF
     {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```